# TFS 2012 Query predecessor work items

Tags: tfs

Is it anyway possible to query PBI(Product Backlog Item):s in a heiearchial way

I have a PBI that will have PBI predecessors. These predecessros will in turn in some cases also have predecessors. Fine so, but I want to display the query result in a Hirerachial way so I can get the working order visualized. Is this possible? / Thanks

- PBI 1

  - PBI 2
  - PBI 3

    - PBI 4
- PBI 5

  - PBI 6

Comment: What are PBI:s? Yuo need to be more clear in yor question. Also if you have any code make sure to add it to the post

Answer (score 0):

Use tree query for work items, read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd286705.aspx)